# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latomic: No such file or directory

Tags: make, ld

I am trying to compile some code using gcc. The following error is thrown:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latomic: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Vmk_scalar_mult.mk:66: Vmk_scalar_mult] Error 1
rm Vmk_scalar_mult__ALL.verilator_deplist.tmp
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/.../obj_dir'
make: *** [Makefile:41: link_verilator] Error 2
```

To give some more information about my system, I did `ld -latomic --verbose`, here's the output:

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.38
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   elf_iamcu
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
   i386pep
   i386pe
   elf64bpf
using internal linker script:
==================================================
...
==================================================
ld: mode elf_x86_64
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64/libatomic.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64/libatomic.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libatomic.so succeeded
/usr/lib/libatomic.so
libc.so.6 needed by /usr/lib/libatomic.so
attempt to open /usr/lib/libfakeroot/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/openmpi/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libfakeroot/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/openmpi/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64/libc.so.6 failed
found libc.so.6 at /usr/lib/libc.so.6
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /usr/lib/libc.so.6
attempt to open /usr/lib/libfakeroot/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib32/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/openmpi/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

Here's some information about my current operating system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux wishbringer 5.15.41-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 18 09:20:01 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How do I go about resolving the issue described above?
I have already tried installing `libatomic_ops 7.6.12-1` from https://github.com/ivmai/libatomic_ops

Thanks in advance!

Comment: linker cannot find libatomic. It is fat better to install from your distribution than from github (or other places): distributions integrate it (so in the expected place for developer tools in such distribution and updating the library list). Else you should check where oyu installed it, and add the -L option or the environment variable, updating the library search path

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for your reply. I did `sudo pacman -S libatomic_ops` as well. I see the following in `/usr/lib` : ``` 
libatomic_ops_gpl.so
libatomic_ops_gpl.so.1
libatomic_ops_gpl.so.1.1.2
libatomic_ops.so
libatomic_ops.so.1
libatomic_ops.so.1.1.1
libatomic.so
libatomic.so.1
libatomic.so.1.2.0
```